# Connecting to SQL Server Analysis with a windows user

Tags: sql-server, ssas, adomd.net

How can you impersonate a windows user in a connection to an analysis server - using ADOMD.NET?

Webserver is next to Analysis server, but they are not in a domain. The webservice running on the webserver needs to access the analysis server as a specific windows account.

Is there something I can put in the connection string, or do I need to look into some kind of impersonation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the Impersonator class at:

http://www.codeplex.com/OlapPivotTableExtend/SourceControl/changeset/view/23587#288650

You call it by doing:

```
using (new Impersonator(sUsername, sDomain, sPassword))   
{   
  AdomdConnection connCube = new AdomdConnection(sConnectionString);   
  connCube.Open();   
  //etc   
}
```

The original reference for this information is:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/b35ab490-9a47-4312-b9b1-c22df2348356

I don't want to take credit for someone elses information directly.